What is the most efficient way of stacking two videos using FFmpeg?
I want to stack two videos of a talk together vertically using FFmpeg. One shows the presentation (slides) and one shows the speaker. Since I want to do this for several talks, I'd like to do this in a more general way and as efficiently as possible. Most of the time the videos have different resolutions and aspect ratios.
My current workflow is:

Scale the video with the lower resolution up to match the resolution of the other video:
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -c:a copy video1_upscaled.mp4


Stack the two videos:
ffmpeg -i video1_scaled.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 combined.mp4



The videos are between one and two hours long and the commands do take a while to complete. Is there any way of saving some time?
Would it be faster to put black bars/borders around the smaller video instead of scaling it to the size of the other one? Can the stacking be done in a more efficient way? Would it help a lot if those two steps were combined into one?
Some information that might be relevant:

It's always exactly two videos to stack vertically, one above the other.
The quality of the video is not incredibly important, both having the resolution of the video with the lower resolution would be perfectly fine.
Disk space is not an issue.
The resolution and aspect ratio of the videos are known (use any for your example).
Both videos have the same audio.
Both videos have the exact same length.


I think there is no quick way of doing this since the video has to be rendered again when you stack them you can't just use the copy stream as video codec option...

combined into one step → fmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4" -lavfi "[0][1]scale=rw:rh[a]; [a][1]vstack" out.mp4

@БаярГончикжапов I think there might be some typos in your suggestion.

Quote in 2.mp4"? or where? Used ffmpeg version 7

for old ffmpeg use scale2ref [0][1]scale2ref[a][b]; [a][b]vstack

@БаярГончикжапов I assume rw:rh is to be changed to the resolution of the larger video, but this gives me the errors: More input link labels specified for filter 'scale' than it has inputs: 2 > 1  and Failed to set value '[0][1]scale=1920:1080[a]; [a][1]vstack' for option 'lavfi': Invalid argument.

I'm sorry, I forgot, for ffmpeg version older than 7 you have to use scale2ref

Here are four ways of doing what you described:
Method A - basically your method
ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -c:a copy upscaled.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i upscaled.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 A.mp4

Method B - your method, but done as one chain
ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] scale=1920:1080 [a]; [1:v][a] vstack=inputs=2" B.mp4

Method C - Padding (what I assume you meant by black bars)
ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] pad=1920:1080:0:0 [a]; [1:v][a] vstack=inputs=2" C.mp4

Method D - Padding and overlay
ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] pad=1920:1560:0:1080 [a]; [a][1:v] overlay=x=0:y=0" D.mp4

Method    Time (s)
A         29.3567267
B         19.932263
C         14.8910977
D         13.7423037

Notes:

A and B have similar results.
C and D have similar results.
C and D will not resize the smaller video.
If you have different SARs, C and D will look weird.
You can also use overlay_cuda if you have a CUDA card and are prepared to tweak the filters.
I ran this in Windows and compared using Powershell (see below)

function VersionA {
    ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -c:a copy upscaled.mp4
    ffmpeg -y -i upscaled.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 combinedA.mp4
}

function VersionB {
    ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] scale=1920:1080 [a]; [1:v][a] vstack=inputs=2" combinedB.mp4
}

function VersionC {
    ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] pad=1920:1080:0:0 [a]; [1:v][a] vstack=inputs=2" combinedC.mp4
}

function VersionD {
    ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 -i big.mp4 -filter_complex "[0] pad=1920:1560:0:1080 [a]; [a][1:v] overlay=x=0:y=0" combinedD.mp4
}

Measure-Command {VersionA | Out-Default}
Measure-Command {VersionB | Out-Default}
Measure-Command {VersionC | Out-Default}
Measure-Command {VersionD | Out-Default}

Apologies if I misunderstood the question regarding the black bars.
